# I can't install this repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I need to install a python package like so:

```
pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/commit/082405ec4ccb9dd454521b266d5ef04d520c703b#diff-9dd6a8b5c5d51f6352fdddd8ac078096584d3db5f51d6d6f0819d1bc897881ec
```

But when trying I get the error

```
ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-7zvkgwjf\082405ec4ccb9dd454521b266d5ef04d520c703b (downloaded from C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sq3hhdbf,
 content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sq3hhdbf
```

I don't understand this error. Please help

Comment: Did you use pip to install this?

Comment: What do you want to install from the page exactly? The HTML page itself? The repository? The page you linked is a commit. Why do you even use pip for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try installing the archive for the commit rather than the diff between it and another commit.
To download a zip for a commit from github, you can use the following URL:
`https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/archive/{commit}.zip`

In your example, you could use `pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/082405ec4ccb9dd454521b266d5ef04d520c703b.zip` to install the package.